# I really dont understand why after I give input to the code it does nothing

Tags: c#

It seems to be perfectly made and I don't think there is an error behind it. Can someone help me to do analyze this more? Am I missing something ? It is about area conversion anyway.

```
double numberOne = 0;

Boolean programRunning = true;

while (programRunning == true)
{
    OutputMenu();

    int choice = OutputMenu();
    if (choice == 9)
    {
        programRunning = false;
        break;
    }
    Console.Clear();
    InputNumber(ref numberOne);

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        double Result = numberOne / 10000;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " / " + 10000 + " = " + Result);
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        double Result = numberOne / 10000;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " / " + 10000+ " = " + Result);
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
            double Result = numberOne / 100;
            Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " / " + 100+ " = " + Result);
     }
    else if (choice == 4)
    {
        double Result = numberOne * 1.55e+9;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " * " + 1.55e+9 + " = " + Result);
    }
     else if (choice == 5)
    {
        double Result = numberOne / 144;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " / " + 144 + " = " + Result);

    }
}
}

private static int OutputMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. cm2 to m2");
    Console.WriteLine("2. m2 to ha");
    Console.WriteLine("3. ha to km²");
    Console.WriteLine("4. km2 to sq in");
    Console.WriteLine("5. in² to ft²");
    Console.WriteLine("9. Exit");

    int choice;

    bool pass = false;
    while (!pass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the corresponding number to your option. ");
        pass = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice);
        if (pass && (choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3 || choice == 4 || choice == 5 || choice == 9))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
            pass = false;
        }
    }

    return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

private static void InputNumber(ref double number1)
{
    bool pass = false; while (!pass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number");
        pass = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number1);
        if (pass)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried testing a simpler version of the script and check whether that works?

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
double numberOne = 0;


while (true)
{
    int choice = OutputMenu();
    if (choice == 9)
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.Clear();
    InputNumber(ref numberOne);
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        double Result = numberOne / 10000;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " / " + 10000 + " = " + Result);
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        double Result = numberOne / 10000;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " / " + 10000+ " = " + Result);
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
            double Result = numberOne / 100;
            Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " / " + 100+ " = " + Result);
     }
    else if (choice == 4)
    {
        double Result = numberOne * 1.55e+9;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " * " + 1.55e+9 + " = " + Result);
    }
     else if (choice == 5)
    {
        double Result = numberOne / 144;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOne + " / " + 144 + " = " + Result);

    }
}
}

private static int OutputMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. cm2 to m2");
    Console.WriteLine("2. m2 to ha");
    Console.WriteLine("3. ha to km²");
    Console.WriteLine("4. km2 to sq in");
    Console.WriteLine("5. in² to ft²");
    Console.WriteLine("9. Exit");

    int choice;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the corresponding number to your option. Value has to fall between 1 and 5 or 9 ");
        if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice) && ((choice > 0 && choice < 6) || choice == 9))) 
        {
           break;
         }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
        }
    }

    return choice;
}

private static void InputNumber(ref double number1)
{
while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number to be converted");
        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
        {
                number1 = number;
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
}
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 1 warnings
jdoodle.cs(67,103): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)'
jdoodle.cs(68,9): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement
jdoodle.cs(71,8): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `else'
jdoodle.cs(95,246): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `end-of-file'


It leaves that error

Comment: Dude, show me the entire code maybe I could help, and also don't just merely copy & paste the code, I have added static void Main() just not to get you confused. As you know, all the functions have to be declared outside of the static void Main().